# android using media scanner for SD card

Tags: android, save, media, sd-card, android-mediascanner

hi to all 
im trying to save an image to an SDcard and im having a problem using the media scanner to scan the new saved file so that it is immediately available

the errors are in the following lines

```
new String[] { file.toString() }, null, // error: file cannot be resolved

new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() { 
// error: MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener cannot be resolved to a type
```

this is my code:

```
public void saveToSDCard(Bitmap bitmap, String name) {
        boolean mExternalStorageAvailable = false;
        boolean mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
            mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = true;
            Log.v(TAG, "SD Card is available for read and write "
                    + mExternalStorageAvailable + mExternalStorageWriteable);
            saveFile(bitmap, name);
        } else if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
            mExternalStorageAvailable = true;
            mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
            Log.v(TAG, "SD Card is available for read "
                    + mExternalStorageAvailable);
        } else {
            mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
            Log.v(TAG, "Please insert a SD Card to save your Ad "
                    + mExternalStorageAvailable + mExternalStorageWriteable);
        }
    }

    private void saveFile(Bitmap bitmap, String name) {

        String filename = name;
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        File sdImageMainDirectory = new File(Environment
                .getExternalStorageDirectory(), getResources().getString(
                R.string.directory));
        sdImageMainDirectory.mkdirs();
        File outputFile = new File(sdImageMainDirectory, filename);
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, outputFile.toString());
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, filename);
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATE_ADDED, System
                .currentTimeMillis());
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/png");
        Uri uri = this.getContentResolver().insert(
                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,

                values);
        try {
            OutputStream outStream = this.getContentResolver()
                    .openOutputStream(uri);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 95, outStream);

            outStream.flush();
            outStream.close();
        // this is where im having the problem  
        // Tell the media scanner about the new file so that it is
            // immediately available to the user.
            MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this,
                    new String[] { file.toString() }, null,
                    new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                    Log.v("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
                    Log.v("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);
                }
            });
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Unable to create file, likely because external storage is
            // not currently mounted.
            Log.v("ExternalStorage", "Error writing " + file, e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: "file" is not declared.
And do you forget import android.media.MediaScannerConnection?

Comment: i imported the mediaScannerConnection and still its giving me the same problem....??!! and the only fix that is showing is "Fix project setup.."

Answer (score 4):

I got this working nicely with the static method [scanFile](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaScannerConnection.html#scanFile%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20android.media.MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener%29)

And here is my code:

```
String filePath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getAbsolutePath() + "/" + fileName;    
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, new String[] { filePath }, null, null);
```

Hope that helps...

Answer (score 4):

Or can use via Intent:

```
//Sends a broadcast to have the media scanner scan a file

private void scanMedia(String path) {
    File file = new File(path);
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    Intent scanFileIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, uri);
    sendBroadcast(scanFileIntent);
}
```

See: [Files Media Scanner with Intent](http://thinkandroidsimple.blogspot.com/2014/03/how-to-run-media-scanner-in-android.html)

Answer (score 2):

[MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener.html) is only available since API level 8. Same thing for the scanFile() variant that you are trying to use. Check your minSdkVersion (and targetSdkVersion) in the manifest.

If you need your app to be compatible with versions of Android before Froyo, then you should use the [scanFile(String path, String mimeType)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaScannerConnection.html#scanFile%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) variant. It is not static, so you need to instantiate and cache the connection, eg in onResume():

```
scanner = new MediaScannerConnection(this, null);
scanner.connect();
```

Then, whenever a file is being saved:

```
if (scanner.isConnected())
    scanner.scanFile(someFile, null);
```

Don't forget to call scanner.disconnect() in onPause().

Answer (score 0):

You use `File file;` in your code, but you don't have this object Instead you use `File outputFile` in other part of code. So you need to use `outputFile.getAbsolutePath()` in your `MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(...)`.